# Is there a way to keep javascript timer in sync across multiple tabs?

Tags: javascript, timer, synchronization, local-storage

I've made a javascript time and stored the time in local storage. When time hits 0 alert pops up saying you should login again, it is not an idle timer it is a session timer. The problem is that if I open 5 tabs of same webpage the timer reduces 5 from local storage and time runs short.

I want to make it as all the pages runs on same time and if there's a logout popup on 1 page it should be on other pages as well.

Comment: What do you store in localStorage, the elapsed time? Why not store the start time or end time and check if it has surpassed?

Comment: Probably not. IIRC modern browsers snooze/throttle activity on inactive tabs to improve performance for active ones. It's unlikely timers across tabs will remain in sync.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to be specific without more details. It doesn't sound like you really want to store a count, though, but rather a date/time when the expiration message should happen (then if you need it for display purposes, you can calculate how many seconds away that is). For one thing, timers in inactive tabs are run less frequently (or not at all), so relying on subtracting from a local storage value isn't going to be a reliable means of showing a message after X minutes.

You may well want to have messaging between the pages so they can coordinate (for instance, when one tab has determined it's time for the message, it could broadcast a message so other tabs also show the message, even if they haven't done a recent check). You can use a [`BroadcastChannel`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BroadcastChannel) for that.

Something *vaguely* like the following.

Setting up the channel:

```
const bc = new BroadcastChannel("your-app-messaging");
```

When processing a successful login:

```
localStorage.setItem("message-time", Date.now() + (SESSION_DURATION_IN_SECONDS * 1000));
bc.postMessage("login-succeeded");
```

Periodically:

```
const messageTime = Number(localStorage.getItem("message-time") ?? NaN);
if (isNaN(messageTime)) {
    // (Handle the odd case where no message time is set)
}
if (Date.now() >= messageTime) {
    bc.postMessage("show-message");
    // ...show the message...
}
```

Responding to messages from other tabs:

```
bc.addEventListener("message", (msg) => {
    // Process messages from other tabs
    switch (msg.data) {
        case "login-succeeded":
            // ...hide the message if showing it...
            break;
        case "show-message":
            // ...show the message...
            break;
    }
});
```

That's only a very rough sketch, but it should get you started.